# Could not work out a closure returned from a method capturing a member variable

Tags: rust, closures, move-semantics, lifetime, borrowing

I am trying to implement a method for a struct which returns a closure `move`-capturing one of its members. The rationale is that the member is `Copy` and so the closure could copy it and shouldn't be tied to the struct lifetime. However, it doesn't compile.

I was hoping Rust won't insist on `copy`ing the `&self` reference, and by that keeping the reference to the struct tying the closure lifetime to the struct lifetime. When it didn't compile I expected this in the error message, but - somewhat surprisingly - I am not sure that's the exact problem.
The anonymous lifetime which restricts the closure is the function lifetime, which is the lifetime of `&self` - not of `self`. As I `move` it, I really don't get what's the problem.

I actually have two questions:
The first, why does the function lifetime restrict my closure? (Could be a misunderstanding of the error message on my side, which I'd love pointed out).
The second, how can I force the `move` of a struct member without copying it to a `temp` variable (just before returning the closure) and inside the closure using this `temp` (which works, but is inelegant in my eyes).

Here's a simplified version of my code:

```
struct Struct {
    member: usize
}

impl Struct {
    fn func(&self) -> Box<dyn Fn(usize)->usize> {
        Box::new(move |argument: usize| {
            self.member + argument
        })
    }
}

fn main() {
    let s = Struct { member: 4 };
    println!("{}", s.func()(5));
}
```

This, when compiled, gives this:

```
error[E0495]: cannot infer an appropriate lifetime due to conflicting requirements
 --> src\main.rs:7:18
  |
7 |           Box::new(move |argument: usize| {
  |  __________________^
8 | |             self.member + argument
9 | |         })
  | |_________^
  |
note: first, the lifetime cannot outlive the anonymous lifetime #1 defined on the method body at 6:5...
 --> src\main.rs:6:5
  |
6 | /     fn func(&self) -> Box<dyn Fn(usize)->usize> {
7 | |         Box::new(move |argument: usize| {
8 | |             self.member + argument
9 | |         })
10| |     }
  | |_____^
  = note: ...so that the types are compatible:
          expected &Struct
             found &Struct
  = note: but, the lifetime must be valid for the static lifetime...
  = note: ...so that the expression is assignable:
          expected std::boxed::Box<(dyn std::ops::Fn(usize) -> usize + 'static)>
             found std::boxed::Box<dyn std::ops::Fn(usize) -> usize>

error: aborting due to previous error
```

Comment: Note that using `self.member` in the closure will use the value of `member` at the time of calling the closure while using a temporary variable will use the value of member at the time of calling `func`. This is a big semantic difference and the compiler is not allowed to change that just to allow you to avoid adding one line of code to create a temporary.

Comment: @mcarton Just a thought: As much as I understand, Rust ownership rules prohibit mutation of immutably-referenced data. Couldn't that prevent the semantic difference between the two? Anyway, I get it. but isn't there a way for me to signal I want to `move` the member itself?

Answer (score 2):

> The first, why does the function closure restricting my closure?

Inside the method, `self` is actually a reference, due to it being declared as `&self` in the method signature. Using a reference inside a `move` closure will move the reference, but not the underlying value.

The immediate errors that you are seeing are because the `Box` returned from the method contains a reference to the struct, but could outlive the struct. If this were allowed, the closure could access a dangling pointer, which Rust forbids.

> The second, how can I force the move of a struct member without copying it to a temp variable

In order to avoid referencing `self` in the closure, this is what you will have to do. You cannot move a struct member *without* copying (or cloning) it - otherwise the struct would be left incomplete. This is a completely normal thing to do in Rust. For example:

```
impl Struct {
    fn func(&self) -> Box<dyn Fn(usize) -> usize> {
        let temp = self.member;
        Box::new(move |argument| {
            temp + argument
        })
    }
}
```

If you don't need the struct again after calling `func` then you can take `self` by value instead:

```
impl Struct {
    fn func(self) -> Box<dyn Fn(usize) -> usize> {
        Box::new(move |argument| {
            self.member + argument
        })
    }
}
```

This works because `self` is moved into the closure. It is no longer usable anywhere else however.